# comparing date conflicts in java

Tags: java

i have two dates with me `startDate` and `endDate`

from method parameters i am getting newStartDate and newEndDate

And now i need to check `newStartDate` and `newEndDate` are not in between or even conflicting with `startDate` and `endDate`

for example:

```
start date = 11/03/2016
end date = 11/15/2016


newStartDate = 11/16/2016
newEndDate = 11/23/2016
(^^^This one should return true)

newStartDate = 11/01/2016
newEndDate = 11/02/2016
(^^^This one should return true)

newStartDate = 11/04/2016
newEndDate = 11/12/2016
(^^^This one should return false)

newStartDate = 11/01/2016
newEndDate = 11/05/2016
(^^^This one should return false)

newStartDate = 11/12/2016
newEndDate = 11/22/2016
(^^^This one should return false)  

newStartDate = 11/01/2016
newEndDate = 11/24/2016
(^^^This one should return false)

newStartDate = 11/01/2016
newEndDate = 11/03/2016
(^^^This one should return false)
```

please help me to write java code for this kind of logic.

Comment: Please search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to compare dates is to convert them to `Date` object first. This can be done as follows:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("DD/MM/YYYY");
Date startDate = dateFormat.parse("11/03/2016");
Date endDate = dateFormat.parse("11/23/2016");
```

Once you have all your dates in `Date` variables then your check for overlap is pretty trivial:

```
boolean overlap = newStar.compareTo(endDate) <= 0 && newEnd.compareTo(startDate) >= 0;
```

It's not clear in your question if ranges that end or start on the same date are considered overlapping. If they are not then you can change then use `<` and `>` rather than `<=` and `>=`.

**Update**

As @BasilBorque points out, the classes above have been superseded by those in java.time. A better solutions now would be:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/DD/YYYY");
LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.parse("11/03/2016", formatter);
LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.parse("11/23/2016", formatter);
```

Comment: This is old-school advice. Those are troublesome old date-time classes, now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes. Furthermore this code is using date-time values when the question asks for date-only values.